# How to prevent page reload using form.submit() to submit as a method in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

How to prevent page refreshing on firing form submission programmatically in ReactJS?
I've tried this code:

```
const myForm = () =>
    <form onBlur={(e) => {
      if(!e.relatedTarget || (e.relatedTarget.form !== e.activeTarget)) 

        e.currentTarget.submit((e) => {
          e.preventDefault();// page reloads before this callback
          debugger
        });
      }
    }}
    onSubmit={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();//// page reloads before this event
      debugger
    }}>
    ...
 </form>
```

**My goal is to submit form onBlur from this form (when a user fills all the fields and clicks outside of the form)**

I've already checked these solutions but they dont work:

[Prevent page reload when submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113048/prevent-page-reload-when-submit)

I dont consider iframes
[Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `e.currentTarget.requestSubmit()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit)). Read about differences with `submit` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit).

Or you may simply define a submit handler function and provide it to both `onBlur` and `onSubmit` form properties.

```js
const handleSubmit = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault()
  ... 
}

return (
  <form 
    onBlur={(ev) => if (shouldSubmit(ev)) handleSubmit(ev)}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  >
  ...
  </form>
)
```

Without resorting to native form submission. If your use case allows that.

Comment: >"Or you may simply define a submit handler function and provide it to both" -
Yeap, I've though about this, but the project uses Final-Form lib and its validation logic is tied with onSubmit event.